# Curly brackets not getting replaced on xargs command

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs, echo

I've been trying to run this command. However, I'm getting some rather unexpected results.
It seems that it's an obvious overlook on my part, but I can't figure it out.

Here's what I tried:

Given that I have a file.txt on the current directory:

```
find ./ -name *.txt -print0 | xargs --null -I {} echo {}
```

This successfully returns:

```
./file.txt
```

However, if I modify it to echo to a file, like so:

```
find ./ -name *.txt -print0 | xargs --null -I {} echo 'some string' > {}.alt
```

The results are not what I would expect:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121     5 Mar  5 20:33 {}
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121   908 Mar  5 04:32 file.txt
```

The desired output would be to have a file named `file.txt.alt` with `some string` as content.

If someone could lend a hand, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: My ultimate goal would be to run something like this:

`for d in */; do (find ./ -name *.txt -print0 | xargs --null -I{} echo -ne '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > {}.alt; find ./ -name *.txt -print0 | xargs --null -I{} iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 {} >> {}.alt; echo "$d"); done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell sets up the redirection before your pipeline is run. Instead, you could use something like

```
find ./ -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "some string" > "$f".alt; done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you!